# query an exchange distribution list

Tags: vb.net, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to find some code that I can use in vb.net 4.0 to query the our exchange 2013 server.  It will be housed on a web server and that server does not have outlook installed on it.  Looks like I need to use EWS to do this but I've tried a lot of code snippets and still have not been able to figure this out.  The distribution list i'm trying to query is in the public folders/Office Contacts.  I've tried examples that use nesting to go through the public folder seen there is no deep traversal but I'm not doing something right there.  I am not posting code because i'm not sure it would help.  I was hoping someone has already done this and would give me some nuggest of info to get me started.

The examples I've found do not query the distribution list but rather add to it.  It's not that I haven't tried... I've got hundreds of lines of code from different places that I've tried and tried to learn from.. but i'm not getting it done.  Anyway.. help would be great.

Sorry about not posting any code.. I actually thought I deleted this post.. but i'll post the code that is now working for me.  This code does a query to the public folder and then grabs some of the data about each contact in that contact list.

```
Public Sub MS()
    Dim oTheListS As New List(Of TheList)
    Dim service As New ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1)
    service.Credentials = New WebCredentials("userid", "password")
    service.AutodiscoverUrl("email@address")

    'Get Public Folder
    Dim sf As SearchFilter = New SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "Office Contacts")
    Dim rrRes As FindFoldersResults = service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.PublicFoldersRoot, sf, New FolderView(1))
    Dim OfficeContacts As Folder = rrRes.Folders(0)
    'Find the Distribution List
    Dim dlSearch As SearchFilter = New SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ContactGroupSchema.DisplayName, "Merit Board")
    Dim ivItemView As New ItemView(1)
    Dim fiResults As FindItemsResults(Of Item) = OfficeContacts.FindItems(dlSearch, ivItemView)
    If fiResults.Items.Count = 1 Then
        'Enumeate Members
        Dim cg As ContactGroup = DirectCast(fiResults.Items(0), ContactGroup)
        cg.Load()
        For Each gm As GroupMember In cg.Members
            Dim o As New TheList
            o = MS2(gm.AddressInformation.Address)
            oTheListS.Add(o)
            'Dim o As New TheList

            'Dim ncCol As NameResolutionCollection = service.ResolveName(gm.AddressInformation.Address, ResolveNameSearchLocation.ContactsOnly, True)



            'With o
            '    .Name = gm.AddressInformation.Name
            '    .Email = gm.AddressInformation.Address
            'End With
            'oTheListS.Add(o)

        Next
    End If

End Sub

 Public Function MS2(pEmail As String) As TheList
    Dim o As New TheList
    Dim service As New ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1)
    service.Credentials = New WebCredentials("userid", "password")
    service.AutodiscoverUrl("email@address")



    Dim sf As SearchFilter = New SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "Office Contacts")
    Dim rrRes As FindFoldersResults = service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.PublicFoldersRoot, sf, New FolderView(1))
    Dim OfficeContacts As Folder = rrRes.Folders(0)
    'Find the Distribution List
    Dim dlSearch As SearchFilter = New SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ContactSchema.EmailAddress1, pEmail)
    Dim ivItemView As New ItemView(1)
    Dim fiResults As FindItemsResults(Of Item) = OfficeContacts.FindItems(dlSearch, ivItemView)
    If fiResults.Items.Count = 1 Then

        Dim con As Contact = fiResults.Items(0)

        'Dim ncCol As NameResolutionCollection = service.ResolveName(gm.AddressInformation.Address, ResolveNameSearchLocation.ContactsOnly, True)

        With o
            If con.DisplayName IsNot Nothing Then
                .Name = con.DisplayName
            End If
            Dim em As New EmailAddress
            If con.EmailAddresses.TryGetValue(EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1, em) = True Then
                .Email = con.EmailAddresses(EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1).ToString
            End If
            If con.JobTitle IsNot Nothing Then
                .Title = con.JobTitle
            End If
            Dim phy As New PhysicalAddressEntry
            If con.PhysicalAddresses.TryGetValue(PhysicalAddressKey.Business, phy) = True Then
                .Address = con.PhysicalAddresses(PhysicalAddressKey.Business)
            End If

            If con.PhoneNumbers.TryGetValue(PhoneNumberKey.BusinessPhone, String.Empty) = True Then
                .PhoneBusiness = con.PhoneNumbers(PhoneNumberKey.BusinessPhone)
            End If
            If con.PhoneNumbers.TryGetValue(PhoneNumberKey.MobilePhone, String.Empty) = True Then
                .PhoneMobile = con.PhoneNumbers(PhoneNumberKey.MobilePhone)
            End If
            If con.CompanyName IsNot Nothing Then
                .Comapny = con.CompanyName
            End If


        End With
    End If
    Return o
End Function
Public Class TheList
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Email As String
    Public Property PhoneMobile As String
    Public Property PhoneBusiness As String
    Public Property Comapny As String
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property Address As PhysicalAddressEntry



End Class
```

I just got it working so I haven't started to refine it yet.. but hopefully this will help someone else as I didn't find any code that did this

Comment: And with those attempts you tried: no error messages? Publish your attempt that came closest. Your question as it is now does not meet SO standards, and writing execuses for not adding code does not make it a good question.

Comment: I added in code above.. it works.. not sure it's the most efficient.. but at least it works

Comment: Maybe you should then edit your question again, and move your solution to an answer. Or, if you want feedback on your code, remove the question here, and put it on [codereview.se]